# Trying to run puppet yield "Error: Could not find class"

Tags: puppet

Firstly, to be honest I'm pretty new to Puppet world. I'm trying to build a puppet script for my server.

Here's how my puppet structures looks like -

```
.
|-- environments
|   `-- example_env
|       |-- manifests
|       |-- modules
|       `-- README.environment
|-- manifests
|   |-- node.pp
|   `-- site.pp
|-- modules
|   |-- nginx
|   |   `-- manifests
|   |       `-- nginx.pp
|   |-- sudoers
|   |   |-- files
|   |   |   `-- sudoers
|   |   `-- manifests
|   |       `-- sudoers.pp
|   `-- users
|       `-- manifests
|           `-- users.pp
|-- puppet.conf
`-- templates
```

here how my `node.pp` and `site.pp` look like this.

```
# /etc/puppet/manifests/node.pp
node werain {
  include sudoers
}
```

and

```
 # etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
 import 'node.pp'
```

and finally my `sudoers.pp` file look like this.

```
# /etc/puppet/modules/sudoers/manifests/sudoers.pp
class sudoers {
  file { '/etc/sudoers':
    mode: '0400',
    source: 'puppet:///modules/sudoers/sudoers',
    owner: 'root',
    group: 'root'
  }
}
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running the `puppet` command like this.

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules/
```

my `puppet` version is  `3.8.4`

Comment: Whats the hostname of the machine, does it match `werain`? Also import is deprecated, you can put the node declaration straight in the site.pp

Comment: `echo $HOSTNAME` => `werain`

Comment: You can use `nodes.pp`, but then use `manifest=/etc/puppet/manifests` in `puppet.conf`. Better yet, switch to `environmentpath`. Also please note that Puppet is not an engine for "scripts". A *manifest* has a subtly different purpose than a script. (It models state as opposed to action.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a module named `sudoers`, and in it a class with the same name.  Puppet will look for the definition of that class in `modules/sudoers/manifests/init.pp`, but you have put it in `modules/sudoers/manifests/sudoers.pp` instead.  That latter is where Puppet would look for a class named `sudoers::sudoers`.

Comment: The `init.pp` this is correct but the `sudoers::sudoers` does not work.Anyway I will accept the answer.